# Kong in Docker : Configuring API endpoints without curl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kong

Is there a way to add API endpoints in Kong without using curl? I have Kong up and running in a docker container using docker-compose and I would like to be able to pass in a configuration file (or what-have-you) on container spin up that outlines the endpoints I would like setup. Is this possible? This is the closest I have found to a solution : http://blog.toast38coza.me/kong-up-and-running-part-2-defining-our-api-gateway-with-ansible/

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use the YAML driven [Kongfig](https://github.com/mybuilder/kongfig) tool to manage the config of the machine. You could run it external to the container e.g. via a CI process (Jenkins etc.) or in theory add a bootstrap action with Konfig running locally within the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kongfig as Mark said or throught the GUI [Konga](https://pantsel.github.io/konga/)